# Configure set of parameters for a Junit5 parameters

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, junit5, junit-jupiter

I have a gradle project using Kotlin and JUnit5 if it helps.

Currently I have a bunch of parametrized tests to run using `@MethodSource`. A tests with all parameters runs for a quite long time, and during local development itn's enough to run lesser with just one value.

Is it possible to define a switch or a configuration to run all tests, but with limited numbers of parameters?

Solutions tested, which didn't work:

- Edit source method(s) everytime I need to run locally -> this leads to mistakes like "I forgot to uncomment tests".
- Limit tests to a single test with all parameters -> This won't work as I need all tests running on every, may be just with a different parameter.
- Make an abstract superclass, extend two with just different annotations -> I have enough tests to skip this solution, I prefer another way if possible.
- check `System.properties` & `System.env` -> Something didn't work as I'd like to do.

Comment: Is it a single or multiple `@MethodSource`(s)? If there are multiple, are they of the same or different "length"? How would like to configure/limit the parameters for local development (e.g. only first three, 25 %, ...)?

Comment: The original list and method source is the same. More specifically, I'm passing matrix, length of which is dependent on current Java version I'm building with. The best outcome if I could pass no parameters (empty list/stream) or a very specific single one for a local build.

Answer (score 0):

Given [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178887/configure-set-of-parameters-for-a-junit5-parameters#comment133376668_75178887):

> The best outcome if I could pass no parameters (empty list/stream) or a very specific single one for a local build.

A simple solution using a system property:

```java
class SomeTest {

    static final String LOCAL_BUILD_PROPERTY = "com.example.localBuild";

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    void test(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    static Stream<String> test() {
        if (isLocalBuild()) {
            return Stream.of("single param");
        }
        return Stream.of("much", "more", "params");
    }

    static boolean isLocalBuild() {
        return Boolean.getBoolean(LOCAL_BUILD_PROPERTY);
    }

}
```

When you pass `-Dcom.example.localBuild=true`, only "single param" will be used. You can also set this property implicitly, e.g., via a [Maven profile on a specific OS](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#os).

However, the "problem" is that the above solution doesn't report how many tests are actually skipped. A more sophisticated solution may uses a dedicated extension implementing [`InvocationInterceptor#interceptTestTemplateMethod(...)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.9.2/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/InvocationInterceptor.html#interceptTestTemplateMethod(org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.Invocation,org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ReflectiveInvocationContext,org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext)).