# JUnit5: Same parameterized test against two different sets (depending on tags)

Tags: junit, junit5, parameterized-unit-test

I have two different sets of parameter sources for a parameterized test (set 1 being a subset of set 2). Depending on JUnit5 tags I want to execute the same test method either against set 1 or set 2.

Unfortunately neither the annotation [@ParameterizedTest](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.0/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/ParameterizedTest.html) nor [@MethodSource](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.0/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/MethodSource.html) allow to specify a tag.

Obviously I can define two different test methods which have the same functionality but act on different parameter sets but that is very redundant/verbose. Isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75178887/3429133). What you could do: add a `TestInfo` parameter to your `@MethodSource`, it will be automatically resolved. You can then check `testInfo.getTags().contains(...)`. Note that since `@MethodSource` is `static`, this will only work for tags on the class level. But anyway, would you mind adding some sample code?